# Baffling memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm creating a UIViewController and placing it into a UINavigationController. And I'm getting a memory leak...according to everything I've seen, it looks like I'm doing it right by the book:

```
ContactsVC *newVC = [[ContactsVC alloc]init]; 
        [self.navcon pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
        [newVC release];
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Code that you have added looks fine, looks like you have a leak elsewhere.  Look for retained properties that are not released in the dealloc and alloc inits not balanced with a release.  HTH.  Dave.

Comment: Have some more code to show us? ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the leaks instrument, it is identifying the line of code that causes the allocation that is leaked and *not* the actual cause of the leak.

The leak, itself, will be caused by an extra `retain` somewhere in your code.  So, you need to figure out everywhere that said object is being retained and, in particular, which retain is either unnecessary or not balanced by a `release`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in XCode 4 try pressing COMMAND + SHIFT + B. That should tell the compiler to analyze your code and it might give you some hints where you are missing a release. Hope it works...

Comment: Using instruments it is reported as a leak

Comment: Can you post the `- (id)init` method from `ContactsVC` class?